# How to maintain the Firebase Data, if a user reloads the page in Angular 10?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-router

Using Angular with Firebase, and protecting the page by using `AngularFireAuthGuard`.

**Angular Route**

Home -> Profile

Getting the user's whole data from firebase using service in `db.service.ts`

**db.service.ts**

```
      getMemberInfo() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.members.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            this.memberDocs.next(snapshot.data());
            resolve(snapshot.data());
          }, reject);
        });
      }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    this.dbService.getMemberInfo().then((status)=>{
        console.log(status);
        if(!status){
            alert("Not Working");
        }
      })
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any
      {
         
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
              Promise.all([
                  this.getMember(),
              ]).then(
                  () => {
                      resolve(true);
                  },
                  reject
              );
          });
      } 
    
      getMember(){
        return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject)=>{
          this._dbService.memberDocs.t((value)=>{
            this.memberData = value;
            console.log(value)
            resolve(this.memberData)
          })
        })   
      }
```

When our user refreshes the profile page, it will not get the data. I am working on fetching the data from App Component first, and then I can access it anywhere in the application.

When a user comes to a profile page, they will get the data if they want to refresh the page. Please suggest the best approach with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the data whenever the page is loaded with ngOnInit.